# certificate does not match name aws private ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Using  AWS ec2 with a load Balancer and elastic IP.

Im trying to add and SSL certificate but getting the following error.

```
Certificate does not match name shop.domain.com
Subject ip-172-31-19-115
Valid from 13/Jul/2015 to 12/Jul/2016
Issuer  ip-172-********
```

I know ip-172-******** is a private IP and the public IP is 54-*********

My question is how do I get the public IP on the SSL? Below is the steps I took:

```
openssl genrsa -out private-key.pem 2048
openssl req -sha256 -new -key private-key.pem -out csr.pem
```

Then submitted to rapidSSL.

Then add to the load balancer this way. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-update-ssl-cert.html

Via the console not command line.

What am I missing how do I get the public IP on the private.key & csr.pem

Comment: What did you answer to the question "Common name" of the `openssl req` command? It appears that the certificate has the FQDN of the private IP as CN.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, the common name I set was shop.domain.com

Comment: Please verify that the subject is the same for the request and x509 certificate or paste the output of the following commands:
`openssl req -in csr.pem -noout -subject`
`openssl x509 -in {therapidsslcertificatefile} -noout -subject`

Comment: Yes I can confirm that both common names are shop.domain.com in the CSR and the CA. Do you need to restart the server after you update now SSL?

Comment: The SSL error you posted sounds like the wrong cert is being returned; the issuer is a EC2 hostname. If you did a self-signed cert before it looks like that's what's still being returned. The rapidSSL cert hasn't been picked up yet.